# Sine/cosine transforms and even/odd functions

Tags: fourier-transform, integral-transforms

Given any real scalar function on a vector space, $f(\mathbf{x})$, we can break it down into parts that are even and odd under parity as
$$f_{\pm}(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{f(\mathbf{x}) \pm f(-\mathbf{x})}{2}$$
and reconstruct the original function from those parts as
$$f(\mathbf{x}) = f_+(\mathbf{x}) + f_-(\mathbf{x}).$$

The symmetric Fourier sine and cosine transforms are defined as
\begin{align}
    \tilde{f}_c(\mathbf{k}) & \equiv \int \operatorname{d}^dx\, f(\mathbf{x}) \frac{\cos(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x})}{(2\pi)^{d/2}},\ \mathrm{and} \\
    \tilde{f}_s(\mathbf{k}) & \equiv \int \operatorname{d}^dx\, f(\mathbf{x}) \frac{\sin(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x})}{(2\pi)^{d/2}},
\end{align}
respectively. The transforms are symmetric because they're inverted by
\begin{align}
    f(\mathbf{x}) & = \int \frac{\operatorname{d}^dk}{(2\pi)^{d/2}} \left[\tilde{f}_c(\mathbf{k})\cos(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}) + \tilde{f}_s(\mathbf{k})\sin(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x})\right].
\end{align}

Clearly, $\tilde{f}_c(\mathbf{k})$ is even under reflection of $\mathbf{k}$ because cosine is even; similarly, $\tilde{f}_s(\mathbf{k})$ is odd. Less obviously, the cosine transform only depends on the even part of $f$, and the sine transform the odd. This is because $\cos(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x})$ is even in both $\mathbf{k}$ and $\mathbf{x}$, so the integral of $f_-(\mathbf{x})\cos(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x})$ vanishes because the overall function is odd (similarly for $f_+$ and sine).

The even/odd function pattern would seem to suggest that I could define a combined transform function as
$$\tilde{f}(\mathbf{k}) \equiv \tilde{f}_c(\mathbf{k}) + \tilde{f}_s(\mathbf{k}).$$
The question is this: in doing so would I lose any information about the original $f(\mathbf{x})$ (i.e. is it as complete as the $\left[\tilde{f}_c,\, \tilde{f}_s\right]$ pair)? What gives me pause is it seems that combining definitions gives
\begin{align}
    \tilde{f}(\mathbf{k}) & = \int \operatorname{d}^d x \frac{f(\mathbf{x})}{(2\pi)^{d/2}} \left[\cos(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}) + \sin(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}) \right]\\
    & = \int \operatorname{d}^d x \frac{f(\mathbf{x})}{(2\pi)^{d/2}} \sqrt{2} \cos\left(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right),
\end{align}
and given that neither the sine nor cosine transforms are complete by themselves, it seems unlikely that $\cos\left(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ would be complete by itself without $\cos\left(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x} + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$.

Comment: Umm seems like you are forgetting some $j$ somewhere in your final reconstruction, but if you project a signal to orthogonal complete spaces you are not to lose any info

Comment: @keoxkeox Are you talking about $\sqrt{-1}$? If so, then I'm not - the sine and cosine transforms, which can build the Fourier transform as $\tilde{f}_c + j \tilde{f}_s$ , explicitly do not have any imaginary numbers in them.

Comment: Hi, What I am pointing is that for a real signal which is actually a linear combination of sine basis and cosine basis (or complex exponentials),  if you keep sine and cosine TXs you would not lose anything, won't check how you project or reconstruct (referring that you have simply added up), sorry.

Comment: @keoxkeox Right - what I'm wondering is if the combination of sine and cosine TXs into a single real function loses anything.

Comment: You may be interested in the [Hartley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley_transform)

Comment: @PaulEnta Make that an answer, please, especially if you know something about the Hartley transform's completeness/kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hartley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartley_transform) defined (in 1D) as 
$$\mathscr{H}f(\omega)=\frac 1{\sqrt\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\cos(\omega t-\frac\pi4)\,dt$$ is an involution, i.e.
$$\mathscr{H}\left(\mathscr{H}(f)\right)=f$$
Then, you do not loose information in defining the Hartley transform function $\bar f(\mathbf{k})$ as you do. It is a real function related to the real and imaginary parts of the Fourier transform:
$$\tilde f(\mathbf{k})=\tilde f_c(\mathbf{k})+\tilde f_s(\mathbf{k})=\Re\left[(1-i)\mathscr{F}(f)\right]$$